# C++2x highlighting with nvim-treesitter

Tags: c++, neovim

I'm currently working on a small project to experiment with `c++20` and `c++23` features such as range adaptors (`std::views::enumerate`, `std::views::enumerate`, ...), `std::format`, etc. For the last few weeks I've been experimenting with using neovim after getting started with kickstart.nvim, and for the most part it has been great with very few issues.

However, whilst working on this project I've been continually seeing errors in the text buffer such as:

```
No member named 'format' in namespace 'std'
```

```
No member named 'enumerate' in namespace 'std::ranges::views'
```

While the code compiles fine on `g++-13`.

My understanding is that kickstart.nvim uses nvim-treesitter to do this stuff, is there a way I can change the language server it's using for C++ to something like a more recent version of clangd which should hopefully support correct error highlighting for these issues (I'm on macos & have llvm-17.0.2 installed via homebrew)?